# Given a set S which contains exactly 4 vectors which spans P3 can we assume linear independence?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that since the dimension of P3 is 4 and the set contains exactly 4 vectors that linear independence implies spanning but can we assume the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

If the vectors were linearly dependent, I could remove one of them and they would still span $P_3$. But I need *at least* $4$ vectors to span $P_3$ because it is of dimension $4$. Thus the vectors are linearly independent and form a basis.